# Excel data validation against a range with dynamic length on other sheet

Tags: excel

I have data for drop down menus on a separate sheet called "DynamicListItems". The data is each on its own column. I can easily reference the data with `=OFFSET(DynamicListItems!$D$3;0;0;COUNTA(DynamicListItems!$D:$D)-1;1)`

But, I have hundreds of these drop down menus, and each need to be used on a different row. Is there a way to reference the range using the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` or similar way so that I can copy the same formula into each data validation field?

Something like `"=OFFSET(DynamicListItems!$" & COLUMN() & "$3;0;0;COUNTA(DynamicListItems!$" & COLUMN() & ":$" & COLUMN() & ")-1;1)"` would be great, but Excel takes that as a one list option.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I use a named range with `=INDIRECT("DynamicListItems!$" & COLUMN() & "$3:$" & COLUMN() & "$" & COUNTA(INDIRECT("DynamicListItems!$" & COLUMN() & ":$" & COLUMN())))`